# Update multiple rows by values taken from another table

Tags: t-sql, sql-update

Here is what I could master so far:

```
declare @i int = 7;
declare @lat float;
declare @lng float;
declare @point ???; -- what type?

declare @location table(lat float, lng float)

insert @location values (32.097218, 34.770438199999944)
insert @location values (32.083847, 34.775618)
insert @location values (32.1600788, 34.771902)
insert @location values (31.9914283, 34.80780099999993)
insert @location values (32.1574281, 34.775191800000016)
insert @location values (29.5543212, 34.89448429999993)
insert @location values (32.8018919, 34.96268420000001)

while @i > 0
    begin
            -- this is a wrong way to do it
        set @point = (select top (1) * from @location);
            -- must set @lat and @lng here somehow, based on the
            -- one row selected above. Deleting here is not
            -- mandatory, but may be used, if needed.
        delete top (1) from @location;
        update top (1) rest_tbl
        set lat = @lat, lng = @lng
        where lat is null and private_label_id = 3
        set @i = @i - 1
    end;
```

Please don't mind the part, where I'm creating the `@location` variable - in the real world, it is an actual table, I'm just using it for PoC.

Comment: Is there any relation between the `rest_tbl` and `@Location`?

Comment: what decides the top record in your `rest_tbl` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need. If you are on `sql-server 2005 or above` you could use `CTE` and `row_number()` function as below without a loop. Please replace *`cols_that_decides_order`* with correct column(s) to get the top records.

Also I think your `lng` will be rounded up when converting to float (ex; `34.770438199999944 >> 34.7704382`).

```
--Declare the table with auto incremented identity with seed=7 and increment = -1.
declare @location table(mykey int identity(7,-1), lat float, lng float)

insert @location values (32.097218, 34.770438199999944)
                       ,(32.083847, 34.775618)
                       ,(32.1600788, 34.771902)
                       ,(31.9914283, 34.80780099999993)
                       ,(32.1574281, 34.775191800000016)
                       ,(29.5543212, 34.89448429999993)
                       ,(32.8018919, 34.96268420000001)

;with cte as (
   select lat,lng, row_number() over (order by cols_that_decides_order) rn
   from rest_tbl
   where lat is null and private_label_id = 3
)
update c set c.lat = t.lat, c.lng = t.lng
from cte c join @location t on c.rn = t.myKey
```

Comment: @wvxvw: `t` is just a table alias for `@location` table and nothing to do with `CTE`. For ex; `SELECT m.id, m.name FROM myTable m WHERE m.Id=20`. You can use it with as `AS m` as well. Here is `msdn link` for [Table Aliases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455(v=sql.90).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I think Using `Cursor` in this matter will help

```
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR (Select  lat,lng  from @location
where lat not in (Select lat from rest_tbl where lat is not null));

DECLARE @lat Float;
DECLARE @lng Float;

OPEN db_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @lat,@lng;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
        UPDATE top (1) rest_tbl
        SET  lat =@lat,lng =@lng
        where lat is null

       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @lat,@lng;
END;
CLOSE db_cursor;

Delete from  @location
    where lat in (Select lat from rest_tbl where lat is not null)
```